# Data driven perl script

Tags: perl

I want to list file n folder in directory. Here are the list of the file in this directory.

```
Output1.sv
Output2.sv
Folder1
Folder2
file_a
file_b
file_c.sv
```

But some of them, i don't want it to be listed. The list of not included file, I list in input.txt like below. Note:some of them is file and some of them is folder

```
NOT_INCLUDED=file_a
NOT_INCLUDED=file_b
NOT_INCLUDED=file_c.sv
```

Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/intel/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_file    = "INPUT.txt";

open ( OUTPUT, ">OUTPUT.txt" );

file_in_directory();

close OUTPUT;


sub file_in_directory {

   my $path       = "experiment/";

   my @unsort_output;
   my @not_included;
   open ( INFILE, "<", $input_file);
   while (<INFILE>){
      if ( $_ =~ /NOT_INCLUDED/){
          my @file = $_;
          foreach my $file (@file) {
              $file =~ s/NOT_INCLUDED=//;
              push @not_included, $file;
          }
      }
   }
   close INFILE;

   opendir ( DIR, $path ) || die "Error in opening dir $path\n";
   while ( my $filelist = readdir (DIR) ) {
      chomp $filelist;
      next if ( $filelist =~ m/\.list$/ );
      next if ( $filelist =~ m/\.swp$/ );
      next if ( $filelist =~ s/\.//g);
      foreach $_ (@not_included){
         chomp $_;
         my $not_included = "$_";
         if ( $filelist eq $not_included ){
            next;
         }

      push @unsort_output, $filelist;         
    }

   closedir(DIR);

   my @output = sort @unsort_output;
   print OUTPUT @output;   
}
```

The output that I want is to list all the file in that directory except the file list in input.txt 'NOT_INCLUDED'.

```
Output1.sv
Output2.sv
Folder1
Folder2
```

But the output that i get seem still included that unwanted file.

Comment: Question would be more clear if you have the example of the input.txt file. Also: `          my @file = $_;
          foreach my $file (@file) {
 `. It's unclear why @file is an array.

Comment: hi @SachinDangol the input.txt file i already mention like above. I store in array as it has a list of "NOT_INCLUDED" as in input.txt

Comment: `$_` is a single value. `my @file = $_` just creates a one-element array, i.e. `$file[0]` will be equal to `$_`. There's no point in using an array here.

Comment: There are many problems in your code, but most importantly it doesn't even compile: `Missing right curly or square bracket at .code.tio line 53, at end of line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not deviating too much from your code, here is the solution. Please find the comments:

```
#!/usr/intel/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $input_file    = "INPUT.txt";
open ( OUTPUT, ">OUTPUT.txt" );
file_in_directory();
close OUTPUT;

sub file_in_directory {
    my $path       = "experiment/";
    my @unsort_output;
    my %not_included; # creating hash map insted of array for cleaner and faster implementaion.
    open ( INFILE, "<", $input_file);
    while (my $file = <INFILE>) {
        if ($file =~ /NOT_INCLUDED/) {
            $file =~ s/NOT_INCLUDED=//;
            $not_included{$file}++; # create a quick hash map of (filename => 1, filename2 => 1)
        }
    }
    close INFILE;
    opendir ( DIR, $path ) || die "Error in opening dir $path\n";
    while ( my $filelist = readdir (DIR) ) {
        next if $filelist =~ /^\.\.?$/xms; # discard . and .. files
        chomp $filelist;
        next if ( $filelist =~ m/\.list$/ );
        next if ( $filelist =~ m/\.swp$/ );
        next if ( $filelist =~ s/\.//g);
        if (defined $not_included{$filelist}) {
            next;
        }
        else {
            push @unsort_output, $filelist;
        }
    }
    closedir(DIR);  # earlier the closedir was inside of while loop. Which is wrong.
    my @output = sort @unsort_output;
    print OUTPUT join "\n", @output;
}
```

Comment: `/^\.\.?$/xms` matches more than just `.` and `..`. It matches any filename that contains a line of just `.` and `..` anywhere. Why did you add the `/m` flag?

Comment: `chomp $filelist` makes no sense. It's a directory entry, not a line.

Comment: `join "\n", @output` leaves the last line unterminated.

Comment: `next if ( $filelist =~ s/\.//g);` skips over all files with dots in their name.

Comment: `/m` flag is for general regular expressions,  PerlCritic idea. I agree it's not required in this case, even all /xms  is not really required. `chomp $filelist` and  `next if ( $filelist =~ s/\.//g);` was there in the original script, I overlooked. `join "\n"` I added to show user content in quick visual way. Yes, it leave the last line unterminated.

Comment: `/m` is not "for general regular expressions". `/m` changes what `^` and `$` mean. Don't blindly apply the default perlcritic ruleset without understanding what it does (and why it sucks).

Comment: Why create broken text files when it would cost you nothing to fix the problem? `print OUTPUT map "$_\n", @output;` isn't any longer or harder to type (or `say OUTPUT $_ for @output;` in non-ancient Perl).

Comment: `exists` is a better option than `defined` when testing to see if a hash key, well, exists.

Comment: In this case as I create a hash by doing `$not_included{$file}++;` defined is fine.

Comment: @SachinDangol But why use `defined` specifically? To check whether a hash key exists in general, `exists` is the right solution. In this case the values are positive integers, so you could just check `if ($not_included{$filelist})` directly. `defined` is neither here nor there.

Comment: `if ($not_included{$filelist})` is the best for this case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This part of the code makes no sense:

```
   while ( my $filelist = readdir (DIR) ) {
      ...
      foreach $_ (@not_included){
         chomp $_;
         my $not_included = "$_";
         if ( $filelist eq $not_included ){
            next;
         }  # (1)

      push @unsort_output, $filelist;  # (2)
    }
```

This code contains three opening braces (`{`) but only two closing braces (`}`). If you try to run your code as-is, it fails with a syntax error.

The `push` line (marked `(2)`) is part of the `foreach` loop, but indented as if it were outside. Either it should be indented more (to line up with `(1)`), or you need to add a `}` before it. Neither alternative makes much sense:

- If `push` is outside of the `foreach` loop, then the `next` statement (and the whole `foreach` loop) has no effect. It could just be deleted.
- If `push` is inside the `foreach` loop, then every directory entry (`$filelist`) will be pushed multiple times, one for each line in `@not_included` (except for the names listed somewhere in `@not_included`; those will be pushed one time less).

There are several other problems. For example:

- `$filelist =~ s/\.//g` removes all dots from the file name, transforming e.g. `file_c.sv` into `file_csv`. That means it will never match `NOT_INCLUDED=file_c.sv` in your input file.
- Worse, the `next if s///` part means the loop skips all files whose names contain dots, such as `Output1.sv` or `Output2.sv`.
- Results are printed without separators, so you'll get something like
  `Folder1Folder1Folder1Folder2Folder2Folder2file_afile_afile_bfile_b` in `OUTPUT.txt`.
- Global variables are used for no reason, e.g. `INFILE` and `DIR`.

Here is how I would structure the code:

```
#!/usr/intel/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_file = 'INPUT.txt';

my %is_blacklisted;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $input_file or die "$0: $input_file: $!\n";
    while (my $line = readline $fh) {
        chomp $line;
        if ($line =~ s!\ANOT_INCLUDED=!!) {
            $is_blacklisted{$line} = 1;
        }
    }
}

my $path = 'experiment';

my @results;
{
    opendir my $dh, $path or die "$0: $path: $!\n";
    while (my $entry = readdir $dh) {
        next
            if $entry eq '.' || $entry eq '..'
            || $entry =~ /\.list\z/
            || $entry =~ /\.swp\z/
            || $is_blacklisted{$entry};

        push @results, $entry;
    }
}

@results = sort @results;

my $output_file = 'OUTPUT.txt';
{
    open my $fh, '>', $output_file or die "$0: $output_file: $!\n";
    for my $result (@results) {
        print $fh "$result\n";
    }
}
```

The contents of `INPUT.txt` (more specifically, the parts after `NOT_INCLUDED=`) are read into a hash (`%is_blacklisted`). This allows easy lookup of entries.

Then we process the directory entries. We skip over `.` and `..` (I assume you don't want those) as well as all files ending with `*.list` or `*.swp` (that was in your original code). We also skip any file that is blacklisted, i.e. that was specified as excluded in `INPUT.txt`. The remaining entries are collected in `@results`.

We sort our results and write them to `OUTPUT.txt`, one entry per line.